# Best way to implement edit functionality in my react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-forms

I have been working on a Reviews react app for some time now and I am running into a problem. Reviews can have Review Responses, but each Review can only have one ReviewResponse. I implemented functionality so that the response form does not show up once a review has a Response. However, I need to implement a method in which the response can be edited.
I thought about going about this by adding an 'Edit' button to the ReviewResponse, and adding an 'onClick' function to that button that renders the ReviewResponseForm component. However, this functionality is not working. Does anybody have any advice on how I should implement this? Thanks

ReviewResponseBox determines if the app should render the current ReviewResponse or the ReviewResponseForm, and passes down the necessary props.

```
import React from "react";
import ReviewResponse from "./ReviewResponse";
import ReviewResponseForm from "./ReviewResponseForm";

class ReviewResponseBox extends React.Component {
  state = {
    reviewResponses: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`reviewResponses-${this.props.review_id}`)) || []
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.reviewResponses !== this.state.reviewResponses) {
      localStorage.setItem(
        `reviewResponses-${this.props.review_id}`,
        JSON.stringify(this.state.reviewResponses)
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    const reviewResponses = this.getResponses();
    const reviewResponseNodes = (
      <div className="reviewResponse-list">{reviewResponses}</div>
    );

    return (
      <div className="reviewResponse-box">
        {reviewResponses.length ? (
          <>{reviewResponseNodes}</>
        ) : (
          <ReviewResponseForm addResponse={this.addResponse.bind(this)} />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }

  addResponse(review_id, author, body) {
    const reviewResponse = {
      review_id,
      author,
      body
    };
    this.setState({
      reviewResponses: this.state.reviewResponses.concat([reviewResponse])
    }); // *new array references help React stay fast, so concat works better than push here.
  }

  
  getResponses() {
    return this.state.reviewResponses.map((reviewResponse) => {
      return (
        <ReviewResponse
          author={reviewResponse.author}
          body={reviewResponse.body}
          review_id={this.state.review_id}
        />
      );
    });
  }
}
export default ReviewResponseBox;
```

Right now ReviewResponseForm only renders if there is not an existing ReviewResponse. But with the edit functionality, I am thinking of rendering this if the edit button on my ReviewResponse component is clicked

```
import React from "react";

class ReviewResponseForm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form className="response-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
        <div className="response-form-fields">
          <input placeholder="Name" required ref={(input) => this.author = input}></input><br />
          <textarea placeholder="Response" rows="4" required ref={(textarea) => this.body = textarea}></textarea>
        </div>
        <div className="response-form-actions">
          <button type="submit">Post Response</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
  
  handleSubmit(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();   // prevents page from reloading on submit
    let review_id = this.review_id
    let author = this.author;
    let body = this.body;
    this.props.addResponse(review_id, author.value, body.value);
  }
} 

export default ReviewResponseForm;
```

ReviewResponse.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './ReviewResponse.css';
import ReviewResponseForm from "./ReviewResponseForm";

class ReviewResponse extends React.Component {

  handleClick() {
   return <ReviewResponseForm />
    }

    render () {
      return(
        <div className="response">
          <i class="reply icon" style={{ color: 'blue'}}></i>
          <br></br>
          <p className="response-header">{this.props.body}</p>
          <p className="response-body">- {this.props.author}</p>
          <div className="response-footer" >
          <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>Edit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  
  }
  export default ReviewResponse;
```

Any advice would be helpful thank you

**Edit #1**
Hi guys,
I changed up my component to re-render when the button is clicked so that the state can change and the form can be rendered, but it is still not showing up. Any advice would be helpful thank you (I actually put my handleClick event handler on the ellipses icon instead)

```
import React from 'react';
import './ReviewResponse.css';
 import ReviewResponseForm from "./ReviewResponseForm";

class ReviewResponse extends React.Component {
  state = {
    formOpen: false
  };
 
 handleClick() {
    this.setState({formOpen: true && <ReviewResponseForm />})
    console.log('click')
    }

    render () {
      return(
        <div className="response">
          <span class="ellipsis">
           <i class="ellipsis horizontal icon" onClick={() => this.handleClick()} style={{ color: 'blue' }}></i>
           </span>
           <br></br>
           <span class="reply-icon">
          <i class="reply icon" style={{ color: 'blue'}}></i>
          </span>
         <span class="response-content">
          <p className="response-body">{this.props.body}</p>
          <p className="response-author"> {this.props.author}</p> 
          <p className="response-date">{new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0].replaceAll("-", "/")}</p> 
          <div className="response-footer">
          </div>
          </span>
            </div>  
            
      );
    }
   
  }
  export default ReviewResponse;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it isn't working because you are not triggering a re-render. You should consider using a boolean in the state.

```
state = {
  isFormOpen: false
};
```

Then when you click the edit button you should set the isFormOpen to true.
The form is rendered conditionally like this:

```
isFormOpen && <Form />
```

Note that a change of the state forces the component to restart its lifecycle.

I edited your code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './ReviewResponse.css';
import ReviewResponseForm from "./ReviewResponseForm";

class ReviewResponse extends React.Component {
  state = {
    formOpen: false
   };

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({formOpen: true})
    console.log('click')
  }

  render () {
    return formOpen ? (<ReviewResponseForm />) : (
      <div className="response">
        <i class="reply icon" style={{ color: 'blue'}}></i>
        <br></br>
        <p className="response-header">{this.props.body}</p>
        <p className="response-body">- {this.props.author}</p>
        <div className="response-footer" >
          <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>Edit</button>
        </div>
     </div> 
    )
  }
} 
export default ReviewResponse;
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your response. I am still encountering a problem, when I click 'edit' the form will not render

Comment: You shouldn't put the component inside the state, the second snippet i wrote goes inside your return statement. If you want to display only the form you can use a ternary operator like:  isFormOpen ? <Form /> : <OtherComponent />

Comment: Thank you! For some reason, I am still getting an error saying that FormOpen element of the state is undefined.